# NextJS - Link element doesn't work with hash id links

Tags: next.js

When I use the Link element (next/link) with the hash id for it to scroll to specific part of a page it just doesn't work. Is there any workaround or something?

```
<Link href="/#kontakt" className={styles.anchor} aria-label="Kontakt">
    Kontakt
</Link>
```

I tried using the specific link (whole url with the #) and `scroll={false}` but neither works.

Comment: I have the same problem here, I need to change from <Link> to <a> and it works

Answer (score -1):

[See the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#disable-scrolling-to-the-top-of-the-page)

Your code works if you add `scroll={false}`

```
<Link href="/#kontakt" className={styles.anchor} scroll={false} aria-label="Kontakt">
    Kontakt
</Link>
```

Comment: "To prevent scrolling to the top / hash scroll={false} can be added to Link"
So, `scroll={false}` id to disable scrolling feature, not to do what he wants